# How can we allow any 2 characters(alphabet/numbers) using regular expression?

Tags: regex

I want to validate if the input user has entered has only 2 characters.
These 2 characters can be any alphabers(in small or upper case) or a number (from 0-9).
for eg. a0
eg. AP
eg. 9P
eg. 56

I tried using below expression but it did not work.
/^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}$/i;

Comment: It should be `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}$`

Answer (score -1):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}$
```

Check the demo [here.](https://regex101.com/r/QaAMww/1)

Your code `^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}$` represents **1 letter** (small or upper case) **AND 2 numbers**, because you've separated them with two pieces of `[ ]`.

Comment: `[A-z]` does not only match letters. It also [matches some punctuation chars](https://regex101.com/r/QaAMww/2).